# How to insert middleware to run before FluentValidation?

Tags: fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-middleware

We have a .net 7 web api, and are using FluentValidation to validate the incoming requests. Apparently FluentValidation hooks itself into the pipeline as middleware, not sure how since that is happening behind the scenes. We have middleware code that does some custom validation on a route to ensure the route itself is valid. That code works correctly, but it seems that FluentValidation is hooked in **before** our middleware, even if we insert the middleware immediately after `app.UseAuthorization();` in program.cs.

The end result is: If the request is to an invalid route, and has validation errors that would be legit if the request itself was legit, then the response shows the validation errors instead of the invalid route message.

The preferred response message would be about the invalid route, not the validation errors.
Is there a way to get our middleware to run before FluentValidation?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Have you tried insert your middleware before `app.MapControllers();`, In your case, I think if client send an invalid route, The project will not let the request invoke the next middleware?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, which sounds plausible, but we're moving away from FV's auto-validation for other reasons, and that gets us around this issue.